# How can I tell react router v4 where to load the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is the thing that confuses me about react router 4. I currently have the routes setup in the main parent component index.jsx. The navigation bar is in it's own component NavBar.jsx.

I want it so that when you click a link in NavBar.jsx, it loads the component into Body.jsx. Currently It loads a component across the entire screen replacing everything.

I believe with React Router 3 you were supposed to do something with this.props.children but if you guys and gals can shed some light on this for me, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Here's the top most component code:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    </div>
  </Router>

, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My components go from Index > Body > TabArea
The navbar is in Index > Banner > HotelTop

Tab Area is the location I want to render the component that HotelTop's navbar chooses.

Comment: Paste code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the place you want your links to load, you have to put a switch and then routes there, but don't put a new router there.

something like...

```js
<div>
  <switch>
    <Route exact path = "/" component={containertoloadpaths}/>
      <Route path = "/Path1" component={component1}
      <Route path = "/Path2" component={component2}
    </Route>
  </switch>
</div>

//You can put code like this anywhere in your app where you'd like your links to load, and they'll load there.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to specify where to render the route component with React Router 4. It is always rendered in-place. So you component will always be a child of the `Route` which has rendered it.

But you can have many `Router` setups in the app — for example one in the `Body.jsx` and another one in a some `Sidebar.jsx` — thus you can achieve the result you need.

Comment: I'll try putting another router there and see what happens.